# What did the sea win?

Tags: expressions

A passage from Arthur Clarke, [*2010: Odyssey Two*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LUoqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT23&dq=%22Floyd+often+wondered+what+Marion+would+have+thought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI_em_5-r8xgIViS2ICh2DNwCR#v=onepage&q=%22Floyd%20often%20wondered%20what%20Marion%20would%20have%20thought%22&f=false):

> Floyd often wondered what Marion would have thought of his strange and beautiful home on the edge of the Pacific. She had never liked the sea, but the sea had won in the end.

Does this mean Marion stop unliking sea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't Marion die in a plane crash off Newfoundland?  That's puts the crash site in the Atlantic.  She dies in the ocean, so it wins in the end, literally.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Marion may have died in the crash of Flight 452 into the sea off Newfoundland, an event that the narrator recalls later in the same paragraph:

> Floyd often wondered what Marion would have thought of his strange and beautiful home on the edge of the Pacific. She had never liked the sea, but the sea had won in the end. Though the image was slowly fading, he could still recall the flashing screen on which he had first read the words ... REGRET TO INFORM YOU LONDON-WASHINGTON FLIGHT 452 REPORTED DOWN OFF NEWFOUNDLAND. RESCUE CRAFT PROCEEDING TO LOCATION BUT FEAR NO SURVIVORS.

If my surmise that Marion was on board flight 452 is correct, the sea "won" because, despite Marion's dislike of it (and presumed effort to avoid it as much as possible), it eventually claimed her life. This isn't an issue of English language and usage, however—except perhaps with regard to the idiomatic sense of the word *won* as Clarke uses it—so much as it's an issue of narrative intent in a plot event that the author presents in the form of a miniature flashback.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not (though out of context that interpretation is just about possible).

A more likely interpretation is that the author is referring obliquely to a competition or struggle between Marion and the sea (which may not have been mentioned before). The use of the *irrealis* perfect conditon "Marion would have thought" suggests that the competition was for his attention: the sea won, and Marion lost.

**Edit**: It's very unclear though, and I see that deadrat has offered another interpretation, based on knowledge of events in the book.